# Using Scrapy for to get background image on CSS Style sheet

Tags: python, css, web-crawler, scrapy, background-image

I am starting to use Scrapy, a crawling library for Python. After searching a lot, I still haven't found a way to crawl background-images in CSS style-sheets. For example, let's suppose I need the url of the store image from this [store](http://www.apple.com/retail/alamoana/). By inspecting it, I realized that the image URL I need is here (in the CSS style sheet):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1068px)
.store-page .image-store-hero {
    background-image: url("http://images.apple.com/retail/alamoana/images/alamoana_hero_medium.jpg");
}
```

How do I get to crawl "http://images.apple.com/retail/alamoana/images/alamoana_hero_medium.jpg" by using xpath on:

```
<figure class="image-store-hero store-hero-alamoana"></figure>
```

which is the figure that contains the image as a background-image.

Or what is the best way to get the store image URL?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is: there is no way to get the image with XPath from the site.

As you already found the image URL is located in the CSS of the site. This means you have to load the CSS file with Scrapy and parse the response which is now a CSS content and not an XML meaning you cannot use XPath on a non-XML document.

However there are some libraries which could be used to parse the CSS -- so based on the `class` attribute of the `figure` tag you can find the appropriate CSS class definition and extract the background image from there.

Comment: Can you give examples of libraries used to parse CSS in python?